# Pragma to Hide Warning: the field used in the where condition may contain null values

Tags: abap, pragma, opensql

I'm looking for a pragma I can use to hide the compiler warning generated when a field used in the WHERE condition of a select may contain NULL values in the database.

Having read SAP note 1088403, I am aware of the possible issues here but I cannot apply the solutions suggested there since I'm using a range, not a single value in the WHERE clause. In either case this is legacy code that was never found to be defective (as far as we know) and will be replaced before long.

However while I'm rewriting other sections of the program, I'd like to disable this warning with a [pragma](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenpragma.htm). Could anyone tell me what pragma I'd be able to use for this?

Example Select:

```
SELECT d~matnr d~werks d~lgort d~bdmng k~maktx
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE itab
FROM resb AS d
INNER JOIN makt AS k ON d~matnr = k~matnr
WHERE
    k~spras = syst-langu
    AND d~werks = p_werks
    AND d~matnr IN s_matnr
    AND d~bwart IN r_bwart.
```

Note that I've since replaced this select with one using a dynamic where clause which also hides the warning since the compiler obviously can't check a text-based where.

Comment: Could you please provide a tiny piece of code? Also, the pragma `#EC * ` applies to everything.

Comment: I've added an example select as requested. As for the pragma you mentioned, I believe it's actually a pseudo comment to disable warnings from Extended Program Check. These pseudo comments are made obsolete by pragmas and using both in one program will trigger a EPC warning that can't be deactivated (according to the ABAP reference). Additionally the warning I encounter is not generated by the EPC but is a compile time warning that this pseudo comment does not seem to disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the extended syntax check over a program with this snippet in, you will see that it specifically states there is no pragma to suppress this (emphasis mine):

Program: <program_name>  Row: <row>
Syntax check warning
The field "BWART" used in the WHERE condition may contain NULL values.
Internal message code: MESSAGE GYT
**Cannot be suppressed using a pragma or pseudo-comment**

Comment: Good to know that this can be mentioned here, I'll make sure to check it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

WRONG !

CORRECT ANSWER:

It can be suppressed using pragma: ##SELECT_NULL_VALUES[your_field]

example: ...AND bwart EQ lc_mov_type_261 ##SELECT_NULL_VALUES[BWART] .

I was receiving the warning for field BWART, so took a look into long text and it says:
This message can be handled using a pragma (refer to Pragmas).
Pragma (compulsory parameters highlighted):
SELECT_NULL_VALUES[BWART]

So I've used it and the warning message is gone.

Careful: you need to use the pragma BEFORE the dot.